# F#: the namespace is not defined

Tags: module, compilation, f#, namespaces

I have this F# project `Rm.Accounting.Domain`
with the following files (and in that order):

- `Model.fs`: `module Rm.Accounting.Domain.Model`
- `Commands.fs`: `module Rm.Accounting.Domain.Commands`
- `Events.fs`: `module Rm.Accounting.Domain.Events`

and the last one causing problems `Behaviour.fs`:

```ml
module Rm.Accounting.Domain.Behaviour

open Rm.Accounting.Domain.Commands
open Rm.Accounting.Domain.Events
open Rm.Accounting.Infrastructure

let a = 42
```

Which leads to two errors:

- `Behaviour.fs(3, 20): [FS0039] The namespace 'Domain' is not defined.` -> `open Rm.Accounting.Domain.Commands`
- `Behaviour.fs(4, 20): [FS0039] The namespace 'Domain' is not defined.` -> `open Rm.Accounting.Domain.Events`

Without that file `Behaviour.fs` the project can compile, I am not sure to understand why those two imports cause some troubles.

Comment: In what order are these files listed in your project?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin like specified in my post

Comment: I don't see `Behavior.fs` in that list.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin "and the last one causing problems `Behaviour.fs:`"

Comment: How do you know that they're in that order?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I ordered them manually in Rider.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin hm I think you made a point, seems that reordering the files in Rider did not really update the fsproj accordingly... well it seems it does most of the time, but I guess there was either a bug or the position was not saved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, it seems that for some reasons despite reordering files in Rider, the `fsproj` didn't really get updated right.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Behaviour.fs" />
        <Compile Include="Model.fs" />
        <Compile Include="Commands.fs" />
        <Compile Include="Events.fs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Rm.Accounting.Infrastructure\Rm.Accounting.Infrastructure.fsproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

Re-organising the fsproj, did the trick:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Model.fs" />
        <Compile Include="Commands.fs" />
        <Compile Include="Events.fs" />
        <Compile Include="Behaviour.fs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Rm.Accounting.Infrastructure\Rm.Accounting.Infrastructure.fsproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I've seen this behavior in Visual Studio before (I know you're using Rider, but just FYI).

Comment: @JimFoye that's good to know, just in case the same behaviour occurs in VS, I will know where to look for.

Comment: I just got this in VS Code as well